# Get all data from all tables (Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

```
data = Program.joins(:program_schedules, :channel).
        where(
         "program_schedules.start" => options[:time_range], 
           "programs.ptype" => "movie",
            "channels.country" => options[:country]).
      where("programs.official_rating >= ?", options[:min_rating]).
      group("programs.id").
      order("programs.popularity DESC")
```

This query retrieve only the "programs" table (I think because the "group by" clause).
How I could retrieve all data from all tables (programs, programs_schedules, channel) ?

> class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> belongs_to :channel
> has_many :program_schedules

**Ruby on Rails 3.2**

**Postgresql 9.2**

Comment: Maybe you should check (and show us) the generated query.

Comment: How I could print the generated sql query?

Comment: I don't know. RoR is your toy. You could always pull it from the postgres log.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [eager loading of associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations) provided by the `includes` method ?

> Eager loading is a way to find objects of a certain class and a number of named associations. This is one of the easiest ways of to prevent the dreaded 1+N problem in which fetching 100 posts that each need to display their author triggers 101 database queries. Through the use of eager loading, the 101 queries can be reduced to 2.

---

**Update:**
You can get the SQL as a string by appending `.to_sql` to your query. `.explain` can also help.

If you want to get the data as a hash and no more as model instances, you can serialize the result of the query and include the associations using `.serializable_hash` :

```
data.serializable_hash(include: [:program_schedules, :channel])
```

You can define which fields to include using `:except` or `:only` options in the same way as described here for `.as_json` (which acts similarly) :
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: I tried, but I get "undefined method `serializable_hash' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcded83c468>". I cannot figure out why

Comment: Try `as_json` instead. The options are the same.

Comment: Seems works, but it this way I lose all instance methods. How I could go back to a ActiveRecord instance (after .as_json)?